# How do I pass a collection/ list of results into a SQL IN Statement in Groovy?

Tags: sql, groovy, soapui

Using Groovy in SoapUI/ ReadyAPI, I am trying to pass the results of one query into another query's IN statement to be able to run an assertion against the results. However, I am not getting the results I want.

Here is what I have now. I am getting the groupNumber from a JDBC query and passing it to the first query to get all associate contracts. I am saving those results to a collection.

I then take the results of that query and turn it into inStatement. I need to have the results wrapped in single quotes, separated by commas.

After that is where things go downhill for me. Currently, I have the results of my query saving to a collection, maybe this is not the best way? If I try to pass $inStatement in the query, I get an empty collection. If I try to pass the code I am using to create inStatement, I get compilation errors for unexpected tokens (this varies depending on how I try to pass the code, wrapped in double quotes, single quotes, etc. but always get a compilation error).

This is my code:

```
def groupBillPolicies = []
sql.eachRow("SELECT column1 as column1 FROM table1 WHERE groupnumber = $groupNumber") {row ->
groupBillPolicies.add(row.column1)
}

String inStatement = groupBillPolicies.collect{"'$it'"}.join(",")

def sqlDataObjects = []
sql.eachRow("select trim(column2) as column2 from table2 where contract in ($inStatement) order by date desc fetch first 1 rows only") {row ->
sqlDataObjects.add(row.column2)
assert 'Validation Text' == row.column2
}
```

I have log.info after the inStatement to see what would be passed and it looked correct to me. Each value was wrapped in single quotes and separated by a comma, but again, passing that into my second query returns an empty collection.

I have also tried the code below instead of creating a collection of results in the first query.

```
 def groupBillPolicies = sql.rows("SELECT column1 as column1 FROM table1 WHERE groupnumber = $groupNumber")
```

This is returning results in a format that I can not use.

```
[[Column:Value], [Column:Value]]
```

I was able to remove the "Column:" from the string using replaceAll, but I cannot remove the brackets around each value.

How would I go about correctly passing in a collection into an IN statement?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Are you sure, you getting the above string as response?  or xml response? How do you want use the above data? Can you post the data resembling to your response?

Comment: I am trying to validate the database after a web service runs. Nothing in the web service response is written to the database. I pass in a group number in the request, the service gives a success. Behind the scenes, the service updates the database for all contracts associated with the group number I give it. For example, I give it '123', the service will update A, B, & C that are all linked to 123 with a specific value. I want to make sure that specific value is updated for all contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def response = [["Column1":"Value1"], ["Column2":"Value2"]]
response.collect{ item ->
   item.collect {
         println "key : ${it.key}, value : ${it.value}"
   }
}
```

I believe you can execute your sql query inside `item.collect`

Comment: Thanks. This got me going in the right direction. I moved my sqlDataObjects collection inside the item.collect and used ${it.value} in my IN statement.